# Private VLANs/Port Isolation on HP ProCurve 2524

Tags: vlan, hp-procurve

I am trying to set up Private VLANs (as described on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_VLAN)) on a HP ProCurve 2524, but I can't find any references to it in the [online manual](http://ftp.hp.com/pub/networking/software/2500-MgmtConfig-Oct2005-59692354.pdf).

Searching the internet hasn't yielded much either (my google-fu is weak here) though I've found some vague hints that the switch might not support it at all.

Can anybody give me pointers? (Am I looking all the wrong places? Does the feature have a different name in HP-lingo? Or do I have to buy a new switch to get support?)

**Edit:** It is to be used in a condominium with ~20 apts, so it's all about protecting the users from malconfigured wifi routers and other idiocies. The switch sit behind a Soekris/PFSense firewall that takes care of NAT/QoS/DHCP.

**Edit №2**: It all turned out to be fairly simple. After updating the switch firmware (hooray for HP doing free updates 10+ years after initial release!), it's done thusly:

```
> config
> port-isolation
Answer ‘y’
> port-isolation e 1-22 mode private
> show port-isolation
> write memory
```

Now ports 1-22 (residents) can only talk to port 23/24 (router/debug port).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all switches support private VLAN's. I don't believe the 2524 provides full private VLAN support. Some of the later firmware versions did introduce port isolation, but there are some significant limitations when using port isolation like:

- Port Isolation is intended only for networks that do not use VLAN tagging. (The switch must 
  be in the default VLAN configuration before you configure port-isolation.)
- Multiple VLANs are not allowed on the switch. If multiple VLANs exist on the switch, delete them and return the ports to the original default configuration as untagged members of VLAN 1. (VLAN configuration changes are not supported if port-isolation is running on the switch.)

The latest [release notes](http://cdn.procurve.com/training/Manuals/2300_2500-RelNotes-F0572-59903102.pdf) contains more information on port isolation and how to configure it.

Comment: +1 The 2524 does not support Private VLANs, only regular VLANs. The Port Isolation really isn't Private VLANs, though it does share some of the functionality. Not surprising given their age and target audience at release.

Comment: @ChrisS I've edited the question to clarify what features of Private VLANs I do actually need. Can you clarify if those are the features supported by the 2524?

Comment: Right. I've caught up with one of the network guys at work, and he believed that port isolation is what I need. Thanks for the quick and thorough replies!